# How to disprove that $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}=\text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_l\}$ if $x_i\in \text{ span }\{y_1,...y_l\}\ \forall i=1,...,k$？

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, infinity

If $y_1,...,y_l$ are vectors in vector space V and $x_i\in \text{ span }\{y_1,...y_l\}\  \forall i=1,...,k$, how to disprove that span$\{x_1,...,x_k\}=\text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$.

In my perspective, either $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subsetneq\text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$ or $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\supsetneq \text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$ or both.

Since $x_i\in \text{ span }\{y_1,...y_l\}\  \forall i=1,...,k$, $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}=a_1y_1+...+a_ly_l$, meaning any vectors in $\text{ span }(X)$ can be linearly combined by vectors in $\text{ span }(Y)$. Therefore $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subseteq \text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$.

It is possible that vectors $\text{ span }(X)$ are $0$ and therefore they cannot linearly combine to for all possible vectors in $\text{ span }(Y)$, and thus $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\supsetneq \text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$. So $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\ne \text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$

However, I sensed my proof redundant and incorrect. Could anyone fix it?

Comment: I'm confused about your statement. Are you trying to prove that, given your hypotheses, $span\{x_1,\cdots ,x_k\}\neq span\{y_1,\cdots,y_l\}$? Or are you trying to find a counter example to: if <hypotheses>, then $span\{x_1,\cdots ,x_k\} = span\{y_1,\cdots,y_l\}$?

Comment: Formulation nitpicking: Actually, you cannot disprove that the spans are equal (which would mean to prove that the spans are different) because it *may happen* that they are equal. In fact, the conditions given are compatible with  $x_i=y_i$. - Instead we can disprove that the spans are always equal (that is we disprove "If A then B", instead of: If A we disprove B)

Answer (score 1):

To disprove a statement all you need is one counterexample.

As you observed you have for sure $\mbox{ span } \{ x_1,.., x_k\} \subset \mbox{ span } \{ y_1,.., y_l\} $. So this part cannot fail.

This means that you must come up with a single example such that $\mbox{ span } \{ y_1,.., y_l\}$ is not inside $\mbox{ span } \{ x_1,.., x_k\}$.
And as you said picking $x_i=0$ seems like a good idea.

So build your example: How many $y's$ do you think you need, and what can they be? How many $x'$s, and what do you want them to be?

Comment: Thanks, but suppose I am proving span$\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subseteq $span$\{y_1,...,y_1\}$. I am wondering which of my first part need to be corrected added?